# Merging two objects with useContext and state?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-context

So i have this problem where it doesn't merge the two objects since **refsContext** is empty when useEffect gets called after render. It ends with only one of the refs in the object. `useEffect(() => {setRef(something)}, [ref]);` results in an infinite empty object loop. Did i miss something?

***refs.context.jsx***

```js
import { createContext } from "react";
const refsContext = createContext({});
export default refsContext;
```

***Same code over multiple files***

```js
/** @jsx jsx */
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import refsContext from "../../context/refs.context";

const StackoverflowExample= () => {
  const projectsRef = useRef(null);
  const [ref, setRef] = useContext(refsContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRef({ ...ref, projects: projectsRef.current });
  }, []);

  return (
     <section ref={projectsRef}></section>
  );
};

export default StackoverflowExample;
```

***App.jsx***

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Pages from "./Pages";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import refsContext from "./context/refs.context";


const App = () => {
  //Default Contexts
  const refsHook = useState({});

  console.log(refsHook[0]);

  //All my wrappers/providers for my App
  return (
    <refsContext.Provider value={refsHook}>
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Pages/>
       </BrowserRouter>
    </refsContext.Provider>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```